# Socket io keeps console logging user connected version 2.x.x

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a basic node express/socket example app from the socket.io official website (linked pasted below) and i noticed that when a user connected, the 'connection' even just kept firing over and over again.

So i found a post ([Socket IO chat repeating user connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906889/socket-io-chat-repeating-user-connected)) saying that there is a bug in socket.io 2.x.x and when i reverted to socket.io 1.3.7 this issue did stop, is this a confirmed bug, and we should roll back to a 1.x.x version? Or is there a new way of using socket.io that doesn't reflect on the current documentation?

My server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My Client side code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

My server terminal output (which just repeats forever):

```
a user connected
a user connected
a user connected
...
```

Socket.io official example:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Maybe it's the issue with the `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` because I just ran the example in my PC with Socket IO v2.0.4 and it the `user connected` did not repeat

Comment: The repeating forever connection is generally caused by a mismatched client and server version of socket.io.  I wonder if you could have a browser cache issue holding an older version of `/socket.io/socket.io.js`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah i believe that was it. A mismatch in client vs. server versioning. I don't know why the pathing would matter in the answer below, but if you want to submit an answer, i'll star it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since socket.io released version 2.x, there appears to be an issue that causes an infinitely recurring connect, disconnect, connect, disconnect and so on forever if you have mismatched versions of socket.io code on client and server.

This can be further exacerbated by client-side caching which can get the browser client stuck on an older version sometimes.

The usual fix is to make sure you're getting the socket.io client with `/socket.io/socket.io.js` because then the socket.io server sends the client version that matches it exactly.   But, you appear to already being doing that, so I'd guess that you have some sort of browser caching problem.  You can clear the browser cache manually to see if this is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use this for the server:

```
var express = require('express');    
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static('node_modules')); // serve static files
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And this in the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <script src="socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The bug might be with the `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` tag that Socket IO provides.

Comment: Why does this fix anything?  And, why do you blindly want to provide access to the entire node_modules hierarchy with `express.static()`?  I cannot see how this is a good solution.

Comment: Only assumption that the client served by SocketIO is buggy. Entire 'node_modules' was just for getting the socket.io-client script. As rightly said, shouldn't be used in production.

Comment: Okay. I thought the script tag might be the culprit. Might not have been

Comment: That script tag is supported by socket.io.  It automatically adds a route for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

Comment: Yeah. I couldn't see any other issue that might have happened. So suggested getting the client directly from the package.